# How to reload celeryconfig.py?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I'm running a script, celery_client.py, that issues commands with [some task from task.py.delay() in a for loop. I also have a celery.py, celeryconfig.py, and task.py. While my client script is running, I have a procedure that modified the celeryconfig.py to reflect a new broker.

I basically want to reload the celeryconfig.py module, and as a consequence, everything else that uses it (including task.py). The problem is, I don't know how to reload celeryconfig.py. There are solutions such as autoreload and broadcast to reload task modules, but how to reload celeryconfig?

Is my only option to restart my celery_client script when a change to celeryconfig.py is made?

EDIT: To clarify, my celery workers are daemonized.

EDIT2: I guess my core question boils down to how to reload the celeryconfig module... Reworded my question

Comment: Is this along the lines of what you're looking for or does it not fit your specific use case? http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#autoreloading

Comment: This would have been perfect if it was implemented for modules other than tasks.py https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1025 . It seems that it doesn't work for modules imported by task.py (like celeryconfig!).